# "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible" on fresh installed XAMPP for Linux

Tags: apache, xampp, ubuntu-11.04, lampp

I did a fresh-install of XAMPP for Linux (version 1.7.4) on my Ubuntu 11.04 x64 laptop.
Then I made a link in my htdocs folder to my project folder:

```
$pwd
/opt/lampp/htdocs
$sudo ln -s /home/petra/projects/webapp webapp
$ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody root 4096 2011-08-18 11:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root   root 4096 2011-01-25 15:33 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root   26 2011-08-18 11:42 webapp -> /home/petra/projects/webapp
```

When I opened the webapp in the browser using `http://localhost/webapp`, it only showed "403 Access Forbidden". The error log said:

```
$tail -f /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
[Thu Aug 18 11:43:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /opt/lampp/htdocs/webapp
```

Here is the [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/ajDZ3sMa). Strangely, the `FollowSymLinks` options are already defined (default).

There is a [similar question on the XAMPP forum](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=28676) but I think nobody seems to pay attention to it anymore.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You don't have a `.htaccess` file in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` that disables `FollowSymLinks`?

Comment: there is no `.htaccess` file in the `/opt/lampp/htdocs`

Answer (score 7):

Try to run Apache using your user.

By default Apache runs as "www-data" so edit your apache2.conf, and search for "user" and set:

```
user=youruser
```

Restart Apache and voilà, it should work.

Comment: What a strange solution, I'd suggested the exact opposit : turn ownership of your files to apache.

Comment: @Petra Barus can you unflag this answer as the solution?
This solution is not helpful, since the apache running as www-data is not a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that if I use link from directory outside `/home/petra`, the web-app is working normally. I guess it's because I use `Encrypted Home Directory` setting on my Ubuntu.

I just have to move the project directory outside my home directory to make it work.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with a SELinux policy. If it's the case, you should see related warnings/errors in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I symlinked the document root to code sitting on my encrypted home directory.  I also solved it by running apache as the user who owned the encrypted content.